# How to set timezone on postgresql jdbc connection created by flyway?

Tags: postgresql, jdbc, flyway

I have a postgresql database that I deploy scripts to using flyway. I use the maven flyway plugin to launch the database build against the target database. In that build I have scripts that do things like:

```
create table my_table(
my_date_time timestamp with time zone not null
);

insert into my_table(my_date_time)
select '2000-01-01';
```

The postgresql database timezone is set to UTC. My client machine (that runs the maven/flyway build) is running CEST (UTC+2:00).

When the scripts run, the database interprets the string literal above as '1999-12-31 22:00:00+00:00' and writes that to storage.

It seems that the jdbc client connection created by flyway is not setting its client timezone to UTC, but is taking the timstamp string and interpreting it as '2000-01-01 00:00:00+02:00'.

How can I set the client timezone on the jdbc connection created by flyway to UTC? Is there a setting that can be placed in my flyway.conf file?

If I change my local machine timezone to UTC the problem goes away, but I'd rather not do that on my development workstation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A colleague suggested the following

```
mvn -Duser.timezone=UTC flyway:migrate
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of just giving it a date, which postgres has to interpret, it would be better to fully specify the timestamp:

```
insert into my_table(my_date_time)
select '2000-01-01T00:00:00+00';
```

If that is not possible, you could try running mvn with `-Duser.timezone=UTC` but fully specifying the timestamp is the better option as it leaves no room for misinterpretation or misconfiguration.

Comment: I would love to do that, but the migrations have already been applied to the target database and changing them causes flyway to throw an error. When they were run in, they were run on a server set to UTC. 

Additionally, running mvn with -Duser.timezone=UTC displays the same issue.

Comment: Okay, so they've already been stored incorrectly.  You could create another migration to correct them all.

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't clear. The migrations have been applied on the test/stage/prod envs, but not on my local env, which runs an integration test. I thought about adding a post migration step on my local env only, but its not completely unambigeous which records I would need to update, and I would rather just get it applying the right timezone in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to set session timezone in migration script itself

`SET timezone TO 'UTC';`

Answer (score 0):

i use flyway CLI in a script. so setting correct timezone to the corresponding environment variable before executing flyway command works for me:

```
export TZ=GMT
```