# How can I override the JVM timezone on maven runs?

Tags: maven, flyway

I use maven to run unit and integration tests, and flyway migrations. My machine timezone is set to +2:00. How can override this so that all actions triggered by maven eg:

```
mvn flyway:migrate
```

use UTC as the timezone?

Answer (score 0):

You can configure the TimeZone on the pom.xml of your application when you configure your flyway plugin like this.

```
       <plugin>
            <groupId>org.flywaydb</groupId>
            <artifactId>flyway-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>6.0.4</version>
            <configuration>
                <user.timezone>UTC</user.timezone> //In case of Java 7 or
                <argLine>-Duser.timezone=UTC</argLine> //Incase of Java 8 and above. 
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

You can refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23466219/4396129) answer for more details and [this](https://flywaydb.org/documentation/maven/) for details of Flyway maven configurations.

Comment: After doing this, it seems that the jdbc connection flyway is making is still picking up my local machine timezone, and the database interprets my datetime literals as being in +2:00 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58285143/how-to-set-timezone-on-postgresql-jdbc-connection-created-by-flyway

Comment: Some jdbc drivers need configuration in jdbc url. For eg, `jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/db?useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&serverTimezone=UTC`

Answer (score 0):

A colleague suggested the following argument to the maven invocation

```
mvn <target> -Duser.timezone=UTC
```